# php mysql fetch name with character issue

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Hi i have a list of restaurants name in my db where some of the name comes with character like  `&, @, and ' (quote)`, the way the name are displayed in browser when viewing then are `http://localhost/my-restaurant-new-york` as i use this function to replace empty spaces with dash `-`

```
$businessDetail = strtr($businessDetail, '-', ' ');
```

based on business name an business id will be found and retrieve all the related infos. If in my db i have a name like `My Restaurant New & york` i cause an error in sql as follow

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3.
```

The question now is how can i save the name in the beginning and how to retrieve it back without having an issue with special characters. Thanks

UPDATE: 
i am using zend framework so this is how i save name into db and retrieve back

```
$testMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_TestMapper();
$testModel = new Application_Model_Test();

$bzname =  str_replace("'", '', $this->_getParam('name'));
$testModel->setId($id)
          ->setName($bzname);
$business_id = $testMapper->save($testModel);
```

All link to the business name are translated by this function

```
$this->view->bzurl = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i","-", $result['business_name']);
```

Update2:

```
public function getBusinessId($business_detail)
    {
        $select = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->select();
      $select->from('business',array('business_id'))

               ->where("business_name='".$business_detail."'"); 



        $result = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->fetchRow($select);
        return $result['business_id'];      
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the actual SQL statement where this error is being thrown?

Comment: @MikeBrant ok i done with sample code

Comment: You are still not showing the actual SQL that is creating that error, nor can I determine where in your code you are actually making the database query to understand if/how you are escaping your input data, etc.

Comment: @MikeBrant this is query used to fetch business id based on name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
->where("business_name='".$business_detail."'")
```

should be:

```
->where("business_name = ?", $business_detail)
```

to ensure that the data is correctly escaped. If that's the query generating the error, that should fix your issue. I'd recommend you read up a little on SQL injection and how to avoid it.

Comment: works this is echo result of query
SELECT `business`.`business_id` FROM `business` WHERE (business_name='Hard Rock s Cafe Kuala Lumpur') but return empty result

Comment: Do you have a record with that exact name?

Comment: this is name of records [Hard Rock's Cafe Kuala Lumpur] i use preg_replace to replace empty spaces with dash - to get url so it
turns out to be Hard-Rock-s-Cafe-Kuala-Lumpur as follow $this->view->bzurl = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i","-", $result['business']['business_name']);

Comment: The query won't return a result if the names don't match exactly. Typically in this situation you'd have an additional column in your database that contains the URL-friendly version of the name (in this case Hard-Rock-s-Cafe-Kuala-Lumpur), and you perform the lookup on that column instead.